Confusion regarding the effect of dead time on instability
I'm reading some lecture notes (which I can't copy from or link to) about how dead time causes instability in first-order systems.  The gist is this: we start with an open-loop transfer function
$$G(s) = \frac{Ke^{-\theta s}}{\tau s + 1}$$
Then, after converting to the closed-loop function and plugging in the "Pade approximation" for the delay factor ($e^{-\theta s} \approx \frac{2-\theta s}{2+\theta s}$), we end up with the following:
$$\frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)} = \frac{\frac{2K}{\tau\theta}-\frac K\tau s}{s^2 + \frac{2\tau+\theta-K\theta}{\tau\theta}s+\frac{2(K+1)}{\tau\theta}}$$
I haven't checked all the steps carefully but I'll certainly buy this.  But here's the part that doesn't make sense to me: they go on to say that, in addition to the instability condition induced by the linear coefficient in the denominator that may generate a negative damping factor - which I get - there is another one due to the positive zero $s = \frac 2\theta$ of the numerator, because the root locus always goes from the pole to the zero, so we can end up with a root that has positive real part.  But this makes no sense, because in root locus analysis, the poles and zeros we use to construct the root loci are those of the open-loop transfer function, whereas here it is only the closed-loop function that has this zero.  Am I missing something, or is this just a conceptual error in the notes, and there is really just one instability condition?


whereas here it is only the closed-loop function that has this zero

I think the confusion comes from the substitution of $e^{-\theta s} \approx \frac{2-\theta s}{2+\theta s}$ in the closed-loop function, but not in the open-loop function. If we do the same for the open-loop function, we obtain:
$$G(s) = \frac{K\frac{2-\theta s}{2+\theta s}}{\tau s + 1}$$
, which indeed has a zero at $s = \frac 2\theta$.
